# How to navigate the user to Google Play for Updates

Tags: android

With the help of my database, I have manually coded a method that notify the users once a day is there is an update and that the users haven't updated their app yet. The users see a Alert Dialog and if clicked Yes, they are directed to Google Play to the app, however the app doesn't show the option to update. It only shows uninstall and open even thought there is an update. From this page, if you open another app etc... come back to the same page, then you can see the option to update.

This is the code for the Alert Dialog Positive Button OnClickListener:

```
                        builder.setPositiveButton(newVersion.getPositive(), (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newVersion.getUrl()));
                            intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        });
                        builder.show();
```

url is coming from the database, it is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=#put_your_package_name_here#

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but there is an API for supporting in-app updates https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are just setting the package name in the wrong way. For better detection of the problem try running it directly without database data like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.vending"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If this doesn't work, try replacing `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` with `market://details?id=` and do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent. ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.vending"));
startActivity(intent);
```

After that, you will know which Uri works for you and then you can use it with your logic. To make it more bulletproof I suggest you use both Uri like this:

```
final String packageName = "com.android.vending";
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details? id=" + packageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think "com.android.vending" is required. That is not my package name by the way :) This is what I found on android developer page but does not solve my problem. https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#Instant

Comment: Are you sure that an app with this packagename exists on the Play store?

Comment: Yes, the app opens fine on Google Plays however doesnt show the option to update, it only shows the option to update after the user navigates to something else and lets say clicks back.